# connecting classic ASP to 64 bit sql server

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp-classic

I have to support an old classic ASP server on a win7 64 bit machine.
I followed http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43132/How-to-Setup-IIS-on-Windows-to-Allow-Classic and enabled 32bit applications.
I created a DSN to connect to the SQL server.
the asp connection code is:

```
    Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set RS   = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    Conn.Open "MTNS","sa",""
```

I keep on getting:

> 224|80004005|[Microsoft][ODBC_Driver_Manager]_The_specified_DSN_contains_an_architecture_mismatch_between_the_Driver_and_Application
>   80 - 127.0.0.1
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko

I can see in the task manager that the IIS is running on 32 bit
The SQL server is a SQL server 2012.
I am pretty lost because all the posts I found said the issue was solved after enabling 32 bit applications.

Comment: The bitness of IIS and SQL server do not matter. Is it possible for you to switch to SQL server native client instead of ODBC?

Comment: Did you add the DSN "MTMS" via the odbc manager in Control Panel.  If you did then it's using the 64 bit version of the driver, try DISABLING 32 bit applications. (the 32 bit odbc manager is hard to find, I had a win 7 machine for 6 months before I knew it was there).  Better still, don't use an ODBC connection, use an OLEDB native client conn string instead - the whole connection string would replace `MINS`, see this link - http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/

Comment: I did add "MTNS" via the odbc manager. I can't change the connection string since its a gigantic code someone else wrote and the connection string is in almost each and every file. how can I force the DSN to use the 32 bit driver?

Comment: You should find the 32 bit version of the ODBC manager at C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe - you should add your DSN there.

Comment: As I suggested earlier though, disabling 32 bit applications should make your 64 bit dsn work. Your setup should have both 64 and 32 bit versions of the driver installed. That Code Project article is wrong.  It's the Jet (MSAccess) driver which is 32 bit only, If you're not using Access, or something else which needs a 32 bit component then you can run classic ASP in a 64 bit environment

Comment: I have an ASP classic site running on Windows 2012R2 with SQL 2014 Express, so it's doable :-). Can you connect to your SQL server directly by testing with this connection string: Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=<your servername>;Database=<your db name>;User ID=<username>;Password=<pwd> ?

Comment: Isn't the "architecture_mismatch" referring to ODBC driver vs SQL Server?  If the SQL Server process is running in x64, you have to use x64 ODBC drivers.  I think...

Comment: No @John advice is spot on use the SysWOW64 version of odbcad32.exe to create your dsn will fix the issue.

Comment: thanks John, running the 32 bit ODBC manager solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DSN-less database connection?
Here is what mine looks like:

```
<%
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
b_use_dsn = false   
if (b_use_dsn=false) then
    'SQL_server_string = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=myMachine; Initial Catalog=pubs; User ID=sa; Password="
    path_to_db = application("path_to_db")
    if (path_to_db = "") then path_to_db = "../data"
    Access_string = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & server.mappath(path_to_db) & "/hotkey.mdb"
else
    Access_string = "DSN=hoobajooba"
end if
ConnectionString = Access_string
conn.Open ConnectionString
%>
```

Answer (score -1):

Running Classic ASP on IIS 7.x Checklist:

(1) Do not name site folders with .com, .net, etc at the end.

(2) Create NEW user account:
- [app pool user identity] is user: app_pool_blahblahblah, pw: xxxxxx

(3) In Server Manager, right click "Web Server (IIS)" and choose "Add Role Services". Add IIS 6 Management Compatibility.

(4) In Server Manager under features add SMTP server.
Install IIS6 Resource Kit so you can 
Use Metabase Explorer.
Grant the [app pool user identity] user read access to the /Local Machine/SmtpSvc/ and /Local Machine/SmtpSvc/1/ nodes in the IIS Metabas

(5) In Application Pool, advanced settings:
- set .Net Framework version to "v2.0" <-- fixed issue with default asp doc not working!
- set "Enable 32-bit applications" to TRUE.
- set managed pipeline mode to "Classic". <-- this may not  be necessary.
- under Process Model, change Identity to "[app pool user identity]" account we created.
- be sure "load user profile" is set to FALSE.
- be sure "maximum worker processes" is "1".

(6) Mail: In IIS 6 Management Console:
http://intellitect.com/configuring-windows-smtp-server-on-windows-2008-for-relay/
- Under SMTP Virtual Server Properties:
    -- "Access" Tab --> Relay: add IPs of this box, including 127.0.0.1
    -- "Delivery" Tab --> Advanced: for "fully qualified domain name" put name of box
    -- "Delivery" Tab --> Advanced: for "smart host" put "dedrelay.secureserver.net"
    -- "Delivery" Tab --> Outbound connections: Make sure limits are set to 100.
    -- "Security" Tab --> add "[app pool user identity]" and IIS_IUSRS

(7) In IIS 7.5 under web site:
- Under ASP:
    -- ONLY IF PROBLEM: set enable buffering to "false"
    -- under limits change max req entity and buffering limit to 1024000000
    -- set script language to "vbscript"
    -- set "send errors to browser" to true
    -- set "Enable Parent Paths" to true
- Authentication --> edit "Anonymous Authentication" and set to app pool identity.
- ONLY IF PROBLEM: under error pages: under 404 set to "/home.asp" and "execute URL"
- ONLY IF PROBLEM: edit c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config: change  to "Allow"
- under Management (at bottom) go into "Configuration Editor".
    -- In the dropdown go to System.web --> http runtime and change maxRequestLength to 1024000000
    -- In the dropdown go to System.webserver/security/requestFiltering --> chg allowDoubleEscaping=true

(8) 
Set "Modify" Permissions for [app pool user identity] for the following folders: 
- your web site
- windows\temp
- inetpub\temp
- inetpub\mailroot
- ONLY IF PROBLEM: windows\serviceprofiles\networkservice\AppData\Local\Temp?

AND Set Permissions in registry:
- ONLY IF PROBLEM: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines?

FOR THESE USER ACCOUNTS:
- IIS_IUSRS
- [app pool user identity]
- NETWORK SERVICE

(9) Install and Use Process Monitor to find permissions issues - filter

(10) Make sure SSL v2 and v3 are not being used:
Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
In Registry Editor, locate the following registry key/folder:
HKey_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders
\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0
Right-click on the SSL 2.0 folder and select New and then click Key. Name the new folder Server.
Inside the Server folder, click the Edit menu, select New, and click DWORD (32-bit) Value.
Enter Enabled as the name and hit Enter.
Ensure that it shows 0x00000000 (0) under the Data column (it should by default). If it doesn't, right-click and select Modify and enter 0 as the Value data.
Do the same with SSL 3.0.
Restart the computer.
Verify that no SSL 2.0 or 3.0 ciphers are available at ServerSniff.net or the Public SSL Server Database.

(11) SSL issue where Safari tells client that it needs a certificate. 
- Go into IIS settings for the SSL-protected site. 
- Click on "SSL Settings"
- Choose "ignore".